# c# unable to interact with listbox from another form

Tags: c#

I have the following form with a method called `setIndex`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectName
{
    public partial class SettingsWindow : Form
    {
        internal readonly static SettingsWindow Instance = new SettingsWindow { Visible = false };

        public SettingsWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string defaultsearch = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            Core.RegistryHelper.SaveSetting("Config", "ds", defaultsearch);
            if (defaultsearch == "aaa") {
                Core.LandingUrlOrig = Core.DomainName + "/defaulturl1.php";
            } else {
                Core.LandingUrlOrig = Core.DomainName + "/defaulturl2.php";
            }
        }

        public static void setIndex(int i)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
        }
```

On another form called `MainWindow` during its initialization I call:

```
    public MainWindow()
    { 
        SettingsWindow.setIndex(0);
    }
```

The error I get is:
`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SettingsWindow.listBox1'`

Initially the `listbox` method wasn't static and thus invisible from `MainWindow`. But now, listbox appears to not exist, even if the form has been instantiated. How do I solve this? I'm just learning C#.

Thank you in advance

Comment: SettingsWindow.Instance.listBox1

Comment: You have static method therefore it can be called with out creating the instance, BUT YOU CAN NOT DO listBox1.SelectedIndex = i; WITH OUT CREATING THE INSTANCE OF SettingsWindow

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz: why are you yelling ?

Comment: Is it against rules???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the function `setIndex` is static you need to use the Instance property:

```
 public static void setIndex(int i)
 {
     Instance.listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
 }
```

or don't make that function static and then use instance in the mainwindow function:

```
 public void setIndex(int i)
 {
     listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
 }

public MainWindow()
{ 
    SettingsWindow.Instance.setIndex(0);
}
```